# Detecting when the TextBox has been edited rather than detecting key press?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a note taking program that allows me to switch between notes with a press of a button. This is convenient for me. I have a little safety built in where when I have active notes in the text box, pressed any key on my keyboard while inside that text box and then tried to select a different group of notes it will ask me if I want to change notes without saving.

This works well enough however I need to find a way where it only detects if changes are made to the notes rather than detecting a key press. The reason for this is I am unable to use a `"CTRL-C"` to copy sections of my notes without setting in motion the events that cause the pop up warning. I would like to be able to continue Jumping from one group of notes to another unless an edit has been made to the text inside the TextBox.

If you try to copy any text that you highlight with `"CTRL-C"` then you will see that trying to switch notes will also ask you if you are sure you want to switch. I am trying to avoid this and I figure there should be a way to check if the notes have had any changes rather than detecting `keypress` inside of the TextBox.

I have tried to use `textvariable` with `track` but tkinters text box does not appear to be able to use that option.

Below is simple example of how typing in the text box and then selecting to open a different set of notes will ask you if you want to continue.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class MiniApp(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, *args, **kwargs)
        self.master = master
        self.text_is_edited = False

        self.add_text = Button(self.master, text = "Add text to TextBox", command = self.add_to_text)
        self.add_text.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "we")
        self.add_text = Button(self.master, text = "Add text to TextBox", command = self.add_to_text_2)
        self.add_text.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "we")
        self.text = Text(self.master, width = 35, height = 3)
        self.text.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")
        self.text.bind('<Key>', self.is_text_edited)

    def add_to_text(self):
        if self.text_is_edited == False:
            self.text.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
            self.text.insert("end-1c", "Some other text to work with.\nMore text.")
            self.text.see("end-1c")
        else:
            answer = messagebox.askquestion("Update TextBox",
                    "Are you sure you want change the content of the TextBox? Any unsaved changed will be lost!")
            if answer == "yes":
                self.text.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
                self.text.insert("end-1c", "Some other text to work with.\nMore text.")
                self.text.see("end-1c")
                self.text_is_edited = False

    def add_to_text_2(self):
        if self.text_is_edited == False:
            self.text.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
            self.text.insert("end-1c", "Text to test with.\nMore text.")
            self.text.see("end-1c")
        else:
            answer = messagebox.askquestion("Update TextBox",
                    "Are you sure you want change the content of the TextBox? Any unsaved changed will be lost!")
            if answer == "yes":
                self.text.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
                self.text.insert("end-1c", "Text to test with.\nMore text.")
                self.text.see("end-1c")
                self.text_is_edited = False

    def is_text_edited(self, *args):
        if self.text_is_edited == False:
            self.text_is_edited = True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk() 
    app = MiniApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The text widget keeps track of whether it has been modified or not. You can query the state at any time by calling the `edit_modified` method. It will return True or False. You can use the same method to reset the flag whenever you want -- typically after you've inserted text via code.

Any time the widget is edited this flag will be set to true. Therefore, when you programatically insert text you need to reset this flag to False.

For example:

```
def add_to_text(self):

    # ask the widget if it has been modified
    if self.text.edit_modified():

        answer = messagebox.askquestion("Update TextBox",
                "Are you sure you want change the content of the TextBox? Any unsaved changed will be lost!")
        if answer != "yes":
            return

    self.text.delete(1.0, "end-1c")
    self.text.insert("end-1c", "Some other text to work with.\nMore text.")
    self.text.see("end-1c")

    # reset the flag to false. If the user modifies the widget the flag
    # will become True again
    self.text.edit_modified(False)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan. That worked perfectly. I think with this I will also be able to simplify my other functions that deal with saving if the file has been edited.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: you can also bind to the `<<Modified>>` virtual event if you want a callback whenever the flag changes.

Comment: Is there a way to reset the `<<Modified>>` event like `self.text.edit_modified(False)`. Really your answer was exactly what I needed to make this work. I can now copy date from the text field without changing the `edit_modified()` status. That was my big hangup in my program.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: no, you can't  "reset the `<<Modified>>` event". I don't even know what that phrase means. That event fires every time the flag changes.

Comment: I was thinking along the lines of keeping a True False record of if <<Modified>> event happened and then reset that record. I could probably accomplish this with a variable and edit that variable when the even occurred. Keep record if text was modified after text was inserted is the goal.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech: _"I was thinking along the lines of keeping a True False record of if <<Modified>> event happened and then reset that record."_ - how is that any different from just using the built-in flag?

Comment: If you are talking about `edit_modified` I don't think it would be different. I was just wondering if I could accomplish the same results using `<<Modified>>` as I would using `edit_modified`. The question in my comment wasn't really thought out.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for the `<<Modified>>` event.

However you don't need to bother with that because the Text widget keeps a modified flag itself. Here's an example (with many other code suggestions too):

```
# wildcard imports are bad and lead to bugs. Use proper imports. 
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

TEXT1 = "Some other text to work with.\nMore text."
TEXT2 = "Text to test with.\nMore text."

class MiniApp(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs): # there will never be any positional arguments, you don't need *args
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        # self.master = master # this line is built into tkinter widgets; you don't need to repeat it

        # all widgets should use the Frame as master, not the root window
        self.add_text = tk.Button(self, text = "Add text to TextBox", command = lambda: self.add_to_text(TEXT1))
        self.add_text.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "we")
        self.add_text = tk.Button(self, text = "Add text to TextBox", command = lambda: self.add_to_text(TEXT2))
        self.add_text.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = "we")
        self.text = tk.Text(self, width = 35, height = 3)
        self.text.grid(row = 1, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = "nsew")

    def add_to_text(self, text):
        # don't copy / paste code. Use the computer to do repetitive things for you. 
        if self.text.edit_modified() and not messagebox.askyesno("Update TextBox",
                    "Are you sure you want change the content of the TextBox? Any unsaved changed will be lost!"):
            return # abort!!

        self.text.delete(1.0, tk.END) # this is a modification and will set the modified flag
        self.text.insert(1.0, text)
        self.text.see(tk.END)
        self.text.edit_modified(False) # reset the modified flag to False

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = MiniApp(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Edit: Dammit Bryan beat me again.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But Bryan beat you to it :D. Don't Worry Novel he beats me to the punch often enough as well.

Comment: BTW, the Text widget also has baked in undo / redo stacks which you may be interested in. You can learn all about it in the [official documentation](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/text.htm). The python bindings are `edit_undo()` and `edit_redo()`.

Comment: I am already using `undo = True` I have not however looked into `edit_undo()` and `edit_redo()`. I will take a look thanks.